# Footer Background Image - Entire Page Width?

Tags: css, background-image

I have an image that I want to use as a background-image for my footer.  Its sort of a gradient image, so the  will be white, and the image will fade from its color, to white.  It's not really a repeatable image though.

If I want it to always span the entire width of the page, is this possible without a background-repeat?  Or, because of different monitor sizes, will this be impossible?

The background image I want should only be in the footer of the page.  Like a sticky-footer, it should always stick to the bottom and the content will push it down as needed.  It's about 400px in height.

It could still be a  background (positioned bottom-center) but it can;t take up the whole height, just the width.  And it need to be able to be pushed down (not fixed)

Comment: http://webdesign.about.com/od/css3/f/blfaqbgsize.htm

Comment: not sure why I got all the thumbs down when I clarified the post.  I realized I had been vague only mentioning I wanted full width cover, but not height.  So I clarified that above

Comment: Just a heads up--it's because you could have just searched Google and found the answer pretty easily.

Comment: @MichaelC.Gates hm, but the link you posted don't answer my question.  Im still searching for the answer

Comment: Since it's a gradient, why not just make it really wide and use: background: #fff url(yourimage.gif) bottom no-repeat; or just allow it to repeat.

Comment: The image it self isn't a gradient.  It's a photo.  But it fades gradually to white on the top.  Repeating on X will make it look weird.  How wide is really wide?  I was hoping there a method for doing it where it would accommodate all resolutions and monitor sizes

Comment: Without jQuery, etc., it's going to be tough. You can try adding  "background-size: cover;" to the body style. I think that will make it expand both height and width. How wide is your web site? You might want to just make it the same width as that. It would look nicer. There are so many screen resolutions, that it might end up being a better solution. Think about it--if someone has a really wide screen resolution, it's going to be taller as well.

Comment: it'll never be taller.  The footer will always sit at the bottom, no matter what.

Answer (score 0):

If you're comfortable using CSS3 you can use

```
background: #fff url(image.jpg) center center fixed no-repeat;
background-size:cover;
```

to have the image cover the screen. You'll want to be careful that it is at least a decent resolution though.